# Magento re-generate url-keys for categories

Tags: magento

I must re-generate all url-keys for all categories. 
When I added some main categories i copied them using one of way from forum. 
Everything was going ok, but when i’m copied about 20k categories i saw: when the name has polish letter the rest was cutted: 
Example: 
name of category: Części karoseryjne 
should be: czesci-karoseryjne 
after copy: cz

name of category: Próg zwalniajacy 
should be: prog-zwalniajacy 
after copy: pr

I’m found on polish forum the way to fix it (with polish letters), but it works only with new added categories. 
Now, when i select any category, clear the url-key and click save - the naming is ok, but ....... there is 20k categories… 
Can somebody write how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.errorin.com/open-source/how-to-add-category-programmatically-in-magento-1-7-0-with-custom-field/

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default'); // Default or your store view name.

//get a new category object
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setStoreId(0); // 0 = default/all store view. If you want to save data for a specific store view, replace 0 by Mage::app()->getStore()->getId().

//if update
if ($id) {
  $category->load($id);
}

$general['name'] = "My Category";
$general['path'] = "1/2/23"; // catalog path
$general['description'] = "Great My Category";
$general['meta_title'] = "My Category"; //Page title
$general['meta_keywords'] = "My , Category";
$general['meta_description'] = "Some description to be found by meta search robots. 2";
$general['landing_page'] = ""; //has to be created in advance, here comes id
$general['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE"; //static block and the products are shown on the page
$general['is_active'] = 1;
$general['is_anchor'] = 0;
$general['page_layout'] = 'two_columns_left';

//$general['url_key'] = "cars";//url to be used for this category's page by magento.
//$general['image'] = "cars.jpg";


$category->addData($general);

try {
    $category->save();
    echo "Success! Id: ".$category->getId();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```